# Is there a way to update a <apex:detail> in a visualforce page with a custom save extension?

Tags: master-detail

We have a VF page that were using, and we are displaying the related lists with the standard  tags. Is there anyway we can use a save button feature that can go through and get the related records and update them accordingly to the new inputs? How would you go about that? Would you just do a query with a subquery to the detail object SELECT MASTER (SELECT CHILD FROM) FROM and have an upsert call for that?

Any feedback on this one would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your vf page should have an extension class which can be used to override the save button. the method called by this save button can query the relevant related records of master & update them.